# Replacing external drive, reuse the drive name?

Tags: ssd, external-disk

I want to upgrade my external drive. Due to the small capacity of of my Macbooks HD, the external drive is used to store everything except for applications.

I want to change out the drive and try to avoid spending the next several weeks pointing apps to the new drive whenever an app looks for the old drive.

Yesterday, I put an entire copy of the old drive (lets call it Alpha) onto the new external SSD.

Can I disconnect the old drive (Alpha) and then change the name of the new one drive to "Alpha"? Will my Mac and Time Machine see this new drive as the old?

Comment: It may depend on how you did the copy. A direct clone done with such as Carbon Copy Cloner will be seen as 'the same drive' once you set the name. I've never tried it with a manual copy.

Comment: I did it manually. I’m tempted to try and used Disk Utility to create a copy. If that doesn’t work, restore from latest backup and use Carbon Copy Cloner

Comment: It's one of those tasks you always have the original to go back to, so you can experiment.